# Help selecting an interpretable model to measure the impact of customer journey touchpoints on satisfaction

Tags: interpretation, nonparametric, model, survey

**Context**

I'm working on a project where I need to undestand the impact of customer journey touchpoints on satisfaction. My goal is to create an interpretable model rather than a purely predictive one, as I want to understand the importance of each touchpoint on satisfaction to make informed business decisions.

**Data**

My input variables (X) are binary, representing whether a customer went through a particular touchpoint or not, while my dependent variable (y) is continuous, ranging from 0 to 10. The distribution of satisfaction scores is not normal, with a significant accumulation at 10 and a quick decrease toward 0. On 0 it increases again, resembling a binomial or beta distribution.

Something like that:
[image: y variable distribution (customer satisfaction)]

**Questions**

1. What algorithm or modeling approach would you recommend for building an interpretable model that can handle binary inputs and non-normally distributed continuous outputs, such as my satisfaction scores?
2. In the context of creating an explanatory model rather than a predictive one, should I partition my data into training, validation, and test sets? Is cross-validation appropriate for this scenario? Or I just train the model with all the dataset?
3. Are there any specific techniques or libraries you suggest for addressing the interpretability aspect of the model, given my objectives?
4. How can I assess the significance or importance of individual touchpoints in influencing customer satisfaction using the selected model? And interpret it?

Any help or insights on algorithm selection and modeling strategy would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe start with descriptive statistics, eg: Which touch points are most correlated with satisfaction? Among customers with satisfactions greater than 5, which touch points are most correlated with satisfaction? Among customers who passed through the most correlated touch point, which other touch points are most correlated with satisfaction? You don’t need a model to answer those questions, and they might inform the decisions well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the eda, and found some patterns in the data, but the main problem is to find HOW MUCH each variable (touch points) contributes or not to customer satisfaction. With a model I could get the weight of the variables and decompose de satisfaction into de touch points to understand the impact of each one

Comment: I am not sure that one can “decompose” the satisfaction or isolate the impact of each touch point. Eg: Asking a question to customer support and getting a quick helpful response may increase satisfaction on its own — but three such interactions may be annoying enough to reduce satisfaction.